# Documenting `..`

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm trying to use roxygen to document and export a function I have named `..` -- I use it for some pattern matching and want a name that doesn't take up much space in an expression but I don't want to clash with `.`

It simply looks like this:

```
#' Function for specifying a sequence of patterns/expressions
#'
#' This function is used when you want to test for more than one pattern
#' in parallel
#'
#' @param ... The patterns/expressions to combine
#'
#' @export
`..` <- function(...) structure(list(...), class = "..")
```

However, I get the error

```
Updating pmatch documentation
Loading pmatch
Skipping invalid path:  ...Rd 
Documentation completed
```

I guess that `..` is not a name the man-pages for R likes, but is there any way to create documentation for this function? Or do I have to rename it?

Comment: Note that `..` is also [used in the `data.table`-package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1)

Comment: It isn't defined as a symbol in `data.table`, is it? It is used in meta-programs (and I use it as that for most of my code as well), but I also need it as a function to simplify my code. I don't think it is an exported symbol in `data.table`. I do have a name class with `data.table`, in `:=`, but I can live with that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
#' @rdname dotdot
```

Then it will create dotdot.Rd

Comment: Ah, just found the similar `@name` solution below. Yes, that works. Cheers Colin.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the answer was simple. I just needed to give the function an explicit name using

```
#' @name `..`
```

then it works.